# textarea maxlength attrribute and string length() inconsistencies

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, maxlength

Trying to write the number of remaining characters available, below a textarea. When I add a lot of newlines, the following script does not work as expected:

```
$textarea.keyup(function () {
  $div.text("Remaining characters: " + (parseInt($textarea.attr("maxlength"), 10) - $textarea.val().length));
})
```

When there's a lot of newlines, the script reports more characters available when I'm not able to write anything. Have tried replacing \r\n with just \n and then counting the string length, to no avail.

What's wrong? :)

[JS FIDDLE Link](http://jsfiddle.net/d3athR0n/pGYJN/)

EDIT: Only Chrome (latest -- 27.0.1453.116) does not work as expected

Comment: If you could setup a fiddle, that would be better to get it.

Comment: wow, thanks badzoke. was just about to add this: http://jsfiddle.net/bxFbL/. impressingly similar! :D

Comment: Fiddle works properly in all my browsers, every "enter" hit decreases counter by 1.

Comment: yes Tommi, but when you get to the bottom and you are not able to write anything more (thus you have hit the maxlength attribute), the text still shows that there are remaining characters available. (tested on chrome)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this jQuery plugin: [jQuery MaxLength](http://mimo84.github.io/bootstrap-maxlength/) configuring it in this way:

```
$('$textarea').maxlength({
    alwaysShow: true,
    preText: 'Remaining characters: ',
    postText: ' '
});
```